# Add view from another class

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, addsubview

I have a table view which loads data. This table view has the "PullToRefreshTableViewController" as superclass. So the top of the .h file contains this:

```
@interface NewsTable: PullRefreshTableViewController
```

Since this makes the whole view an tableview I can't add anything like a toolbar on top of this.

So I thought. I'll make a sort of container class. One which has the toolbar in it, and also add the class with the PullRefreshTableView as a subview.

Only problem i'm having that I don't know how to integrate this? What should I do to add the PullRefreshTableView in this container class?

I think it's something like

```
[containerclass addSubView:PullRefreshTableView]
```

But of course this doesn't work

Thnx for your effort!

**Update:**
The working code is:

```
PullRefreshTableViewController *newsFeed = [[PullRefreshTableViewController alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:newsFeed.view];
```

Beware to not release it as soon as you add the subview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing this

```
 PullRefreshTableViewController *newsFeed = [[PullRefreshTableViewController alloc]init];
        [self addSubview:newsFeed.view];
        [newsFeed release];
```

in a view controller it should be

```
PullRefreshTableViewController *newsFeed = [[PullRefreshTableViewController alloc]init];
        [self.view addSubview:newsFeed.view];
        [newsFeed release];
```

Comment: In addSubview v should be small. It was caps. See if this works.

Comment: I also tried that. But that still makes the app hang, but don't even gives an error... I've tried to log the newsFeed.view which gives me the following output: <UITableView: 0x683fc00; frame = (0 20; 320 460); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x5e42dd0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>. So I think the newsFeed.view is ok.

Comment: What do you mean by it hangs. And if u have actions in PullRefreshTableViewController it is better not to release it after adding it as a subview

Comment: Aaaah maaan!!! Thank you so much! I removed the release, and it worked finally. With hangs I meant it freezes and doesn't do anything. But that was thanks to the release probably. Thanks!!

Comment: gr8:) As part of memory management, u can make it an instance variable of the class, allocate it in init and release in dealloc

Answer (score 2):

```
[containerclass addSubview:PullRefreshTableView.view];
```

use this one. Resize ur subview to adjust all the views

Comment: With only this code I can't get it to work. With the help of Simon i've got the following:     PullRefreshTableViewController *newsFeed = [[PullRefreshTableViewController alloc] init];
    [news addSubView:newsFeed.view];
    [newsFeed release]; But this gives SIGABRT at the addSubView line. Any suggestions? Thnx!

Answer (score 1):

```
PullRefreshTableView *tableView = [[PullRefreshTableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, width, height)]; -- use correct values here!
[self addSubview:tableView];
[tableView release];
```

Comment: Thnx! I've tried your option but got an error, I have edited my post with the error. Can you take a look at this?

Comment: What error do you get? Is PullRefreshTableView a UITableView descendant?

Comment: Well, it hangs, and gives me the error in the output which I posted in my original post. My PullRefreshTableView has the following in the .h file @interface PullRefreshTableViewController : UITableViewController. So i think it's an descendant than..

Comment: Ahhh apologies, it is a UIViewController descendant, I thought it was a UIView descendant (as UITableView is). So you need... PullRefreshTableView *tableView = [[PullRefreshTableView alloc] init]; -- use correct values here!
[self addSubView:tableView.view];
[tableView release];

Comment: Or if you have a NIB with the layout in... PullRefreshTableView *tableView = [[PullRefreshTableView alloc] initWithNibName:@"NIBNAME" owner:nil];

Comment: Ok! Thnx, but I still have the same error, though it moved a row down at this line :[self addSubView:newsFeed.view];